# How to create proper Find***.cmake file

Tags: cmake

I wrote a simple Find***.cmake file for my project which works fine on Windows,

```
if(WIN32)
    find_path(Shaderc_INCLUDE_DIR
            NAMES shaderc/shaderc.hpp
            PATH "$ENV{VULKAN_SDK}/Include")
    find_library(Shaderc_LIBRARY
            NAMES shaderc_combined
            PATH "$ENV{VULKAN_SDK}/Lib")
elseif(UNIX)
    find_path(Shaderc_INCLUDE_DIR
            NAMES shaderc/shaderc.hpp
            PATH "$ENV{SHADERC_DIR}/include")
    find_library(Shaderc_LIBRARY
            NAMES libshaderc_combined
            PATH "$ENV{SHADERC_DIR}/lib")
endif()
set(Shaderc_INCLUDE_DIRS ${Shaderc_INCLUDE_DIR})
set(Shaderc_LIBRARIES ${Shaderc_LIBRARY})
```

, but throws an error on Linux. The error message is:

> CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but
>   they are set to NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set
>   and tested correctly in the CMake files: Shaderc_LIBRARY

If I copy this code to my main CMakeLists file it compiles fine on Linux as well. What I'm doing wrong? Is it a bad practice to use environment variables on Linux for this purpose?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A description "does not work" is not the one with which we could help you. How exactly this "does not work" is observed? Do you got an error message? Or some variable has wrong value? Please, [edit] the question post and add **more details** into it. See also [ask].

Comment: For Windows you use `VULKAN_SDK` variable, but for Linux `SHADERC_DIR` variable is used. What the value of the variable `SHADERC_DIR` on Linux? What is **exact path** (and filename) to the library `libshaderc_combined` which should be found according to your assumptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, judging from the code, your module looks in directories specified by environmental variables.

Instead, you should make it search in well-known places, like `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: Thanks! So, instead of using environment variables, I should just symlink the contents to the /usr/lib and usr/include when I'm using a library from github?

Comment: @arrowd: The code in the question looks **both** into specific directories, denoted by package-specific environment variables, and into system-specific directories. This is recommended and widely used way for search things in CMake. Adding symlinks into `/usr/lib` and `/usr/include` is definitely bad idea.